# Java. Modificar aspecto de un botón al ser pulsado

Tags: java, botón

Soy aficionado a la programación y estoy comenzando con java. He creado un botón para que al ser pulsado llame a un procedimiento. El problema es que el procedimiento  tarda 3-4 s en ejecutarse y quisiera que durante ese tiempo
cambiara el texto del botón (de CONECTAR a CONECTANDO).

Dentro del evento ActionPerformed hago el cambio con `boton.setText("CONECTANDO")` y después llamo al procedimiento. Pero se ejecuta al revés, primero ejecuta el procedimiento y una vez que sale del evento hace el cambio de texto.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que 1º modifique el texto del botón y después ejecute el procedimiento? 
¿Por qué este cambio en la secuencia?

Gracias, El código es:

```
   private void bConectarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

             // Cambio el texto original CONECTAR por CONECTANDO                                                         
      bConectar.setText("CONECTANDO"); 

             //Procedimiento que quiero ejecutar. Tarda 3-4 SG En ejecutarse
      arduino.conectar();  

            // Indíca que la acción se ha realizado            
      bConectar.setText("CONECTADO");    // Indica que la acción se ha realizado     
    }
```

El resultado es que ejecuta :

```
1º arduino.conectar() 
2º bConectar.setText("CONECTANDO"); 
3º bConectar.setText("CONECTADO");
```

Es cómo si las instrucciones que alteran el botón fueran ejecutadas al salir del evento.

Comment: Hola, seria de gran ayuda que compartieras tu codigo, para poder guiarte de mejor manera

Comment: Modifica tu pregunta por favor, revisa [ask].

Comment: Agrega una llamada a `bConectar.paintImmediately();` después de cambiar el texto a `"CONECTANDO"`. Si eso funciona, escribiré una respuesta detallada al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

Deberias intentar colocar el ultimo codigo

```
bConectar.setText("CONECTADO");
```

dentro del procedimiento arduino.conectar();

ya que con el Action todo es inmediato al momento de ejecutar dicho evento

Comment: No funciona, todo lo relativo a modificar el botón parece ejecutarse al salir del evento. Además arduino.conectar() se invoca desde otros lugares ajenos a este botón.